# azure cli to add scope to app registration

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

I have a powershell script that runs az cli to add a scope to an existing app registration.

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$serviceAppRegAppId
)

$uuid = [guid]::NewGuid()
$api = @{
    acceptMappedClaims = $null
    knownClientApplications = @()
    oauth2PermissionScopes = @(
        @{
            adminConsentDescription = "admin description"
            adminConsentDisplayName = "admin name"
            isEnabled = $true
            id = "$uuid"
            type = "User"
            userConsentDescription = "user description"
            userConsentDisplayName = "user name"
            value = "amx.read"
        }
    )
    preAuthorizedApplications = @()
    requestedAccessTokenVersion = "2"
} | ConvertTo-Json

write-host "api=$api"

$appRegName = az ad app show --id $serviceAppRegAppId --query displayName
$appRegNameWithoutQuotes = $appRegName.Trim('"')

write-host "Going to add scope to app reg:$appRegNameWithoutQuotes"

# Update app registration with App ID URL and api object
az ad app update `
    --id $serviceAppRegAppId `
    --identifier-uris "api://$appRegNameWithoutQuotes" `
    --set api="$api"
```

If I run this directly from VS Code it works fine. However, when run from an Azure DevOps pipeline and AzurePowerShell@5 task, I get the following error:

> Going to add scope to app reg:apreg-gis-maps-prod-001
>
> ERROR: Property api in payload has a value that does not match schema

Can anyone see which property of the api object it could be complaining about? Also why would this work from vs code terminal but not from Azure DevOps?

Following Jesse's advice, I ran az ad app show which gave:

```json
{
   "api":{
      "acceptMappedClaims":null,
      "knownClientApplications":[
         
      ],
      "oauth2PermissionScopes":[
         {
            "adminConsentDescription":"Read amx data",
            "adminConsentDisplayName":"Read amx data",
            "id":"ff9d6262-eb63-4c94-bdfa-0a33372c87bc",
            "isEnabled":true,
            "type":"Admin",
            "userConsentDescription":"Read amx data",
            "userConsentDisplayName":"Read amx data",
            "value":"amx.read"
         }
      ],
      "preAuthorizedApplications":[
         
      ],
      "requestedAccessTokenVersion":2
   }
}
```

I saved this to a file named from-azure.json, then ran the following:

```
$json = Get-Content -Raw -Path "from-azure.json"
$apiConfig = $json | ConvertFrom-Json

# Expand the knownClientApplications property
$apiConfig.api.knownClientApplications = $apiConfig.api.knownClientApplications | Select-Object -ExpandProperty value
$apiConfig.api.oauth2PermissionScopes = $apiConfig.api.oauth2PermissionScopes | Select-Object -ExpandProperty value
$apiConfig.api.preAuthorizedApplications = $apiConfig.api.preAuthorizedApplications | Select-Object -ExpandProperty value

# Output the custom PowerShell object
$apiConfig
```

The output was as follows:

```
@{acceptMappedClaims=; knownClientApplications=; oauth2PermissionScopes=amx.read; preAuthorizedApplications=; requestedAccessTokenVersion=2}
```

This seems incomplete?

Comment: Did you try upgrading az-cli on the agent? The version on the agent may be different than yours.

Comment: @jessehouwing thanks for your suggestion. I noticed that the devops pipeline was running the latest version of azure cli (2.45.0) whereas I had 2.38.0 on my laptop. I upgraded my laptop to match versions. Now when I run "az ad app show --id $serviceAppRegAppId --query displayName" I get the error: "Continuous access evaluation resulted in challenge with result: InteractionRequired and code: LocationConditionEvaluationSatisfied". I've tried suggestion from the following without success: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/24684

Comment: Try setting a variable in your pipeline `AZURE_IDENTITY_DISABLE_CP1=1` That should trigger early enough in the process to skip access policy evaluation.

Comment: With the environment variable set, the pipeline does then run but hit the same problem as described in the original question: ERROR: Property api in payload has a value that does not match schema

Comment: Do you now also get *THAT* error message locally?

Comment: yes, at least it's now consistently broken :| I've not been able to find any official documentation of the schema of the object required as the api parameter for az ad update. I've tried suggestions from several blog posts and SO answers but no luck so far.

Comment: Can't you configure an app the way you want, then use `az ad app show` to fetch the json payload and then use `get-content -raw template.json | Convert-FromJson` to get the equivalent object structure? That should give you something that, when passed in, has a high chance of working ;).

Comment: Thanks again @jessehouwing, I may be getting closer

Comment: alas no progress, I'm getting "Invalid value specified for property 'id' of resource 'PermissionScope'" but the id is a string guid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was a lack of understanding of how the az command works against Azure. It submits a http Patch request to the Azure api that presents the collection of oauth2PermissionScopes. If any of these scopes currently exist in an active state, they must first be disabled or an error will be raised.